# File execute permissions for automounted USB HDD (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: mount, ubuntu-11.10, automount

I have an issue with Ubuntu 11.10 automounting USB HDDs where the permissions for all files on the mounted volume are set to -rw-r--r-- and I can't change them with chmod.

I don't have the same issue automounting under Mint, all permissions come up as -rwxr-xr-x

which is what I want.

running mount -l from the terminal reveals that the only difference between the Ubuntu and Mint USB HDD mounts is showexec

So I think this is where the issue lies. I have no idea how to modify what Ubuntu does when automounting USB drives, but if I could somehow get it to include the `showexec` command line option then maybe this would fix the problem?

Possibly a modification to /etc/fstab?

Any pointers gratefully received.

Comment: Seems like this answer indirectly covers what you need: http://askubuntu.com/a/24409/34265

Comment: It seems odd that there isn't a simple defacto means of controlling the auto mount options in ubuntu - all I've found are hacks. Some even suggest modifying and recompiling the kernel - seems crazy! All I want is for Ubuntu not to apply the showexec option when performing an auto mount. The fstab route seems popular but its not really what I want to do which is change the generic auto mount process

Comment: The kernel can stay. You *might*, however, have to patch/recompile "udisks", since it has the default options hardcoded. (It might be that Mint packagers did just that.)

Comment: the mint distro just has a *different* fmask hard-coded (which happens to suit my needs)

Comment: i've worked around by just writing a script to unmount the auto mount then remount it manually specifying a suitable fmask. I still think changing the automount options is an obvious thing to want to do with no easy way of doing it?

Comment: @grawity does ubuntu use udisks? just had a look here: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=udisks&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=uk

Comment: @Hiett: Yes, Ubuntu uses udisks, like almost every other Linux distro.

Comment: maybe i need to set the udisks-glue.conf file? I can't find much info on it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct when suggesting on your question the use of `/etc/fstab` to auto mount a USB HDD device.

You haven't provided your USB HDD device specifications, its location or the desirable mounting point, but, here's an example:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/Test ntfs-3g defaults,user,exec,uid=1000,gid=100,umask=000 0 0
```

With this configuration added to my `/etc/fstab` file, I've mounted the device having all privileges over its files. So, every time my system boots, Ubuntu will auto mount the device, or issue a warning if the device isn't found.

- Replace `/dev/sdb1` with your device location:

  To find out your USB HDD device location, you can use at your terminal:

  ```
  sudo blkid
  ```
- Replace `/media/Test` with your target directory:

  The target directory must exist, create it beforehand, using the terminal:

  ```
  mkdir /media/Test
  ```
- Replace `ntfs-3g` with your USB HDD device file system:

  Refer to the [Fstab :: File System Type](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#File_System_Type) for further specifications.

---

**Related reading:** [Fstab - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)